# JBoss AS 7.1 Clustering with JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jboss7.x, cluster-computing

I am trying to cluster enable my JSF 2.1 application (mojarra 2.1, Primefaces) on Jboss AS 7.2 (EAP 6.3)  And I have researched this issue wihtou being able to find an answer.

I have deployed the application to two nodes and logged into the application.  The I shut down the node that was being used and when I try to use the application again, I am directed to a login page.  The have printed the session id and it changes when I hit the new node.

I have deployed a sample cluster bench (https://github.com/clusterbench/clusterbench) and the examples all work, with the exception of the JSF sample.  The session id is always lost when a node goes down.

My web.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <distributable />

...
</web-app>
```

My jboss.web.xml is:

```
<jboss-web version="6.0"
           xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_6_0.xsd">

    <replication-config>
        <!-- The default value is SET_AND_NON_PRIMITIVE_GET, therefore the byte array which is carrying the data is considered
             non-primitive and would cause replication even in read only scenario. -->
        <replication-trigger>SET</replication-trigger>

        <!-- Replicating entire session is the default. -->
        <replication-granularity>SESSION</replication-granularity>
    </replication-config>
  <context-root>/sample</context-root>    
</jboss-web>
```